# How to update cell values in a data frame which depend on values in the preceding cells in the same column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

The values of a cell in a data-frame depends on values in the preceding cells in the same column and values in another column. I am not sure how to update these dynamically. I am trying my best to show an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(50)

df <- data_frame(SlNo = 1:12,
                 Scenario = rep(c(1, 2, 3),4),
                 A = round(rnorm(12, 11, 6)),
                 B = round(rnorm(12, 15, 4))) %>%
      arrange(Scenario) %>% mutate(C = 0, D = 0, E = A*B/2)

df<- add_row(df, .before = 1)

df$C[1] <- 4
df$E[1] <- 6

df$C[2] <- lag(df$C, 1)[2] * lag(df$E, 1)[2]


df$C[3] <- lag(df$C, 1)[3] * lag(df$E, 1)[3]

df

# A tibble: 13 x 7
    SlNo Scenario     A     B     C     D     E
   <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    NA       NA    NA    NA     4    NA   6  
 2     1        1    14    13    24     0  91  
 3     4        1    14    14  2184     0  98  
 4     7        1    13    10     0     0  65  
 5    10        1     2    13     0     0  13  
 6     2        2     6    16     0     0  48  
 7     5        2     1    14     0     0   7  
 8     8        2     7    14     0     0  49  
 9    11        2    13     9     0     0  58.5
10     3        3    11    13     0     0  71.5
11     6        3     9    12     0     0  54  
12     9        3    17    14     0     0 119  
13    12        3    14    22     0     0 154
```

I'd like each cell in column C dynamically update based on values in the preceding cells. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: `accumulate(df$E,\`*\`,.init=4)` should be able to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case it is easier than it looks like.

Just to simplify the question, lets say you have two vectors `a` and `b` defined this way:

```
a <- c(4, rep(0, 9))
b <- 1:10
```

You want to update `a` based on previous values of `a` and `b`. The algorithm as I understand it from your question:

If `i > 1`: `a[i] = a[i - 1] * b[i - 1]`.

Thus `a[1] = a[1]`, `a[2] = a[1] * b[1]`, `a[3] = a[2] * b[2] = a[1] * b[1] * b[2]`, ..., `a[i + 1] = a[1] * b[1] * b[2] * ... b[i]`

Which means that `a[i + 1]` depends only on `a[1]` and *cumulative product* of `b[i]` for all `i = 1...i`, and *does not depend* on all the rest old values of `a`.

Thus:

```
(a[2:length(a)] <- a[1] * cumprod(b[-length(b)]))
# [1] 4       8      24      96     480    2880   20160  161280 1451520
```

Applying this to your example:

```
df$C[2:nrow(df)] <- df$C[1] * cumprod(df$E[-nrow(df)])
df
# A tibble: 13 x 7
    SlNo Scenario     A     B       C     D     E
   <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    NA       NA    NA    NA 4.00e 0    NA   6  
 2     1        1    14    13 2.40e 1     0  91  
 3     4        1    14    14 2.18e 3     0  98  
 4     7        1    13    10 2.14e 5     0  65  
 5    10        1     2    13 1.39e 7     0  13  
 6     2        2     6    16 1.81e 8     0  48  
 7     5        2     1    14 8.68e 9     0   7  
 8     8        2     7    14 6.08e10     0  49  
 9    11        2    13     9 2.98e12     0  58.5
10     3        3    11    13 1.74e14     0  71.5
11     6        3     9    12 1.25e16     0  54  
12     9        3    17    14 6.73e17     0 119  
13    12        3    14    22 8.00e19     0 154
```